# Fragments don't work in app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have question, because I do not know what is wrong. Does not display the activity of activity_main_fragment.xml me and I do not know why. Do you have any suggestions what to change?
I created two fragments fragment_a and fragment_b and I want to display them connected to the fragment_a when you click on an item in a listview information came to me in fragment_b.

Communicator.java

```
public interface Communicator {
    public void respond(int i);

}
```

strings.xml

```
 <string-array name="titles">
        <item>Zmiany</item>
        <item>Ilę</item>
        <item>Trudne pytania</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="descriptions">
        <item>Zmianysadas</item>
        <item>Ilęvcxcvcx</item>
        <item>Trudne pytaxcvcxvxcnia</item>
    </string-array>
```

fragment_a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFBB00" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView22"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_b.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#99CC00">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.odpad.odpadygdansk.FragmentA"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.odpad.odpadygdansk.FragmentB"
        android:layout_width="470dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentA.java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    ListView list;
    Communicator communicator;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        communicator = (Communicator) getActivity();
        list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView22);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
        communicator.respond(i);
    }

}
```

FragmentB.java

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment{
    TextView text;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    }

    public void changeData(int i)
    {
        Resources res = getResources();
        String[] descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);
        text.setText(descriptions[i]);
    }
}
```

EcologicalInformationActivity.java

```
public class EcologicalInformationActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Communicator{ 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(int i){
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentB f2 = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        f2.changeData(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`EcologicalInformationActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` so you should call `getSupportFragmentManager()` in place of `getFragmentManager()`. See documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager%28%29). If your fragments are not already instances of [the support library version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html), you'll need to change that too.